# Python loop seems valid but still get ValueError: Not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a multiindexed DataFrame that I am trying to filter and assign to corresponding variables. The code to filter my DataFrame returns the expected result and if i type everything out without using the for loop or if i ask the for loop to `print` rather than assign to variables it works as expected, but for some reason it returns `ValueError: Not enough values to unpack (expected 8, got 3)` when I use the loop to assign to variables.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

vars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
for v in vars:
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = df.loc[:,idx[:,[v, 'Column 1']]]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: ... what does `df` look like?

Comment: can you share a sample of the dataframe.

Comment: So if you print then you always get 8 values?

Comment: What does `df.columns` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to assign variable names using strings. Try getting rid of the for-loop and putting it in a list comprehension.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

vars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [df.loc[:,idx[:,[v, 'Column 1']]] for v in vars]
```

### Why it works:

***What you were doing***

```
for v in vars: # evaluates each v 1 at a time
    ... = df.loc[:,idx[:,[v, 'Column 1']]] # returns 1 item corresponding to current v
```

since your `df.loc[...]` was evaluating each `v` 1 at a time there was nothing to "unpack" aka you can't unpack 8 variables from a variable such as `x = 11` because it's only 1 item.

Note that had each If your `df.loc[...` returned a collection of 8 items it would have broken out those 8 items into `a`...`h` *overwriting* them each time.

***What I did***

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [df.loc[:,idx[:,[v, 'Column 1']]] for v in vars] # returns _collection_ of 8 items
```

Using a list comprehension i'm just executing all your `df.loc` queries at once returning a *collection* of 8 results. Since there are now 8 items on the right hand side of the `=` assignment, the unpacking works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Could you explain why that worked? It doesn't seem like that change should have made any difference.

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thank you very much for your help!